# Why can I perform stream operations without having to import java.util.streams.Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When doing a stream operation like,

`int sum = list.stream().filter(i -> i > 0).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();`

to get the sum of all positive numbers in a `list`, we are using a `Stream<Integer>` in the intermediary stage, but this does not require the import of `java.util.stream.Stream`.

Now, to do the same thing, when I write,

```
Stream<Integer> stream = list.stream();
int sum = stream.filter(i -> i > 0).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

it produces the exact same results, but I need to `import Stream` since a variable I have declared requires that type.

So, why did the `list.stream()` part in the first way I mentioned not require me to import a `Stream`? I might be missing something very basic here, but I would be very grateful if someone could point it out.

Comment: `import` is just about not needing to write package names.

Comment: When you refer to class `X` you need an `import` to give a hint which package it came from. If you don't actually mention `X` you don't need an import.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need to import a class identifier if you explicitly name it in your source code with an unqualified identifier.

(And there are exceptions to that too ...)

---

The purpose of the `import` statement is to remove ambiguity; i.e. in

```
    Stream<Integer> stream = ...
```

which class does the identifier `Stream` refer to?

- `java.util.stream.Stream`?
- some class that you have written?
- some class in some 3rd-party library?

An `import` statement can say which one.

Examples.

1) The `Stream` class is not named in the source code

```
    // no import required
    int sum = list.stream().filter(i -> i > 0).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

Note that there is no ambiguity here.  The compiler knows what the full class name for the result of the `stream()` call.  The full name was resolved when the list class was compiled, and it has been embedded into the class file.

2) The `Stream` class is named with its fully qualified name:

```
    // no import required
    java.util.stream.Stream<Integer> stream = list.stream();
```

3) The `Stream` class is named with an unqualified name:

```
    // import required
    Stream<Integer> stream = list.stream();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I get that explicit naming in source requires an import. But, what I am struggling with is why that is required.

Comment: The purpose of the `import` statement is to remove ambiguity.  Which class does `Stream` refer to?  `java.util.stream.Stream` or some class in some 3rd-party library?  The `import` statement says which one.

Comment: In the `no import required` section, isn't a `Stream<Integer>` being created in the intermediary stages? Or does the case of inline function calls work without requiring an import, since I already know what type is being returned by the function?

Comment: Ah. I think I see what you mean.

Comment: *"In the no import required section, isn't a Stream<Integer> being created in the intermediary stages?"*  - Yes it is.  But the fully qualified name of the type is known from the signature of the >>compiled<< method you are calling there.  The ambiguity problem only arises when you refer to a class by its simple name in Java source code.